# How to stop Python from truncating print statements?

Tags: python, pandas, printing

I have a print statement that prints a very long big Pandas DataFrame series out, but I need all the information.  When printing, Python gives

`0 [{This is a long stateme.....}]` 
`1 [{This is a long stateme.....}]`

and terminates the print statement with dots.

I want to see the entire print statement without Python terminating it short, is there a setting to change to let print statements print infinite values?

Comment: If you need to see all the data, why not to df.to_csv("mycsv.csv") in order to access it as a csv outside of the terminal?

Comment: That would be a good option, unfortunately, I built a web app and have deployed on a customers infrastructure.  I built in a custom endpoint to allow me to insert new logs into different lines of the code for debugging, but I do not have access the source repo on the customer's machine.

Comment: Ah, so doing a to_csv method would return to the customer's computer while printing allows you to see the result of the endpoint. In that case, how long are the entries in the df?

Comment: They are not too long, each row corresponds to a JSON file.  Each JSON would have about 20 entries.  Unfortunately, Python truncates it after the first output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas allows options to see a set number of rows, as well as width

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", n)
pd.set_option("display.expand_frame_repr", True)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

To increase the number of characters printed ***per column***, use:

`pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", max_characters)`

By default, a column only prints up to 50 characters, this option allows you to print an `max_characters` amount of characters.

See the docs below:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html

Comment: Hi Christina, your answer wasnt exactly correct, but it was indeed in the options link you provided.  I needed the option ("display.max_colwidth") instead to set a specific column's width to be sufficiently large.  I have modified your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
with numpy.printoptions(threshold=numpy.inf):
    print(arr)
```

Comment: Hi Aymen, unfortunately, this did not work.  I am printing the statements with the default Python library.  Additionally, i am printing a pandas dataframe series, not a numpy array, if that changes anything.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provide answers the question.